# Jquery .load() running on Xammp

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, xampp

Does the ajax .load() request work using xammp? I've set up a simple load request that seems to run fine with IE but not chrome. The files are all located within Xammp's HTdocs so I'm not sure why it wouldn't work given that it's a dummy server and ajax works by contacting the server.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: ajax or jQuery by instance has nothing to do with xammp or any web server. Why don't you show us your code?

Answer (score 0):

First check your console, then check if chrome's javascript function is enable and last check your file status, if it is 200 it's ok, but if it's 404,503 etc...